# Coolant issue citroen c4

Tags: coolant, citroen, citroen-c4

How do I drain the old coolant, which is mostly water, in my citroen c4 as I need to add 100% coolant due to overheating problems

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you are having cooling issues, adding pure antifreeze is not going to solve your problems. Pure water, in a closed system, works very well at cooling. A typical 50/50 mix will work even better. If you have a mix right now and you're having overheating problems, I'd suggest you have other issues. Pure antifreeze will only cause you issues, as it is not designed to work that way. (Evans waterless coolant is an exception.)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the Citroen C4 can be a bit of a pain to re-fill the coolant system without trapping air in the system.

There could conceivably be an air-lock if you're having overheating problems.  As Paulster2 says, it's very unlikely a car that overheats on water would not do so on coolant.

The system has a bleed screw in the header tank (adjacent to the brake servo).  You may be better trying to bleed the air out of the system rather than draining and re-filling.

I realise that does not directly answer your question.  The actual answer to draining your system, the question as asked, is to remove the radiator bottom hose and catch the coolant in a suitable container under the front of the vehicle.